# How to get the row of a record in QSqlTableModel?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

i'm new using qt and I didn't find a way to retrieve the row of some element that I know only a field value (email for example).

I have a model(QSqlTableModel) and I want to know what is the row of the record in table "person" with email "a@gmail.com". The QSqlQuery do not return a row, how can I achieve this?

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec(QString("SELECT * FROM person WHERE email = \"%1\";").arg("a@gmail.com"));
// the query.exec do not return rows, but I need to know it, in order to edit some (not selectable) item, using QSqlTableModel::setRecord(int row, ...) for example.
```

Answer (score 2):

Different approachs can be used :

- sweep and test the data over entire table as follow :

  ```
  int getFirstRowWithEmail(
        QSqlTableModel& table, 
        const QString & email)
  {
     int col = table.fieldIndex("email");
     for(int row=0; row<table; ++row)
     {
        QVariant data = table.data(table.index(row,col));
        if(data.toString() == email) 
        {
           return row;
        }
     }

     return -1;
  }
  ```
- filter your data string via a QSortFilterProxyModel :

  ```
  int getFirstRowWithEmail(
          QSqlTableModel& table, 
          const QString & email)
  {
     int col = table.fieldIndex("email");
     QSortFilterProxyModel proxy;
     proxy.setSourceModel(table);
     proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(col);
     proxy.setFilterRegExp(QString("^%1$").arg(email));
     if( proxy.rowcount() > 0) 
     {
         auto proxyIndex = proxyModel->index(0,0);
         auto sourceIndex = proxyModel->mapToSource( proxyIndex );
         return sourceIndex.row();
     }

     return -1;
  }
  ```

beware that we suppose that the field is unique, otherwise one would need to return a list of ids as follow.

```
  std::list<int> getRowsWithEmail(
           QSqlTableModel& table, 
           const QString & email)
  {
     std::list<int> rows;
     int col = table.fieldIndex("email");
     for(int row=0; row<table; ++row)
     {
        QVariant data = table.data(
                           table.index(row,col));
        if(data.toString() == email) 
        {
           rows.append(row);
        }
     }

     return rows;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/sql-sqlstatements.html#navigating-the-result-set).

> QSqlQuery provides access to the result set one record at a time.
>   After the call to exec(), QSqlQuery's internal pointer is located one
>   position before the first record. We must call QSqlQuery::next() once
>   to advance to the first record, then next() again repeatedly to access
>   the other records, until it returns false. Here's a typical loop that
>   iterates over all the records in order:

```
while (query.next()) {
    QString name = query.value(0).toString();
    int salary = query.value(1).toInt();
    qDebug() << name << salary;
}
```

Note that [QSqlQuery::value](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#value) takes a field index.
The fields are numbered from left to right using the text of the SELECT statement.

In your case the fields will be ordered in the same order they were created in since you are using `SELECT *` to return all elements of a row.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but to be more clear, I want to retrieve the row number of some record stored in my model(which is a QSqlTableModel) using some fields that I know beforehand, like email . I don't need of the values of the fields, I already have that, I need to know in which row the searched data is.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here or why but the only way I can think of doing that is to retrieve all rows for the database and then loop over them until you find the row in question. All you would have to do then is have some kind of counter and increment it in each iteration.